# When I update the state, component is not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few items on my website, I am trying to sort them in different orders.
When I change the data object, it is updating itself but unfortunately component are not updating themselves.

I have made sure that db array is updating but update doesn't affect items.

I am using a pseudo database to represent it.

```
function SaleBody() {
const [db, setDb] = useState([
    { img: house1, price: 46000 },
    { img: house2, price: 58000 },
    { img: house3, price: 82000 },
    { img: house4, price: 32000 },
]);
const handleClick = () => {
    setDb(
        db.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.price - a.price
        })
    )
}
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className='sort'>
            <p>Sort By</p>
            <div className="dropdown">
                <img id='dropdown-btn' src={dropdownIcon} />
                <div className="dropdown-content">
                    <a onClick={handleClick} href="#">Price Ascending</a>
                    <a href="#">Price Descending</a>
                    <a href="#">Random</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div className='sale-body-item'>
            <img src={db[0].img} />
            <div className='house-text'>
                <div className='house-text-item'>
                    <h1>For Sale</h1>
                    <p>${db[0].price}</p>
                </div>
                <div className='house-text-item'>
                    <h1>Adress</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum St.</p>
                </div>
                <div className='house-text-item'>
                    <p>3 bedrooms,</p>
                    <p>2 bathrooms,</p>
                    <p>40m2 garden</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <Link to='/item'><button>More Information</button></Link>
        </div>
        <div className='sale-body-item'>
            <img src={db[1].img} />
            <div className='house-text'>
                <div className='house-text-item'>
                    <h1>For Sale</h1>
                    <p>${db[1].price}</p>
                </div>
                <div className='house-text-item'>
                    <h1>Adress</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum St.</p>
                </div>
                <div className='house-text-item'>
                    <p>3 bedrooms,</p>
                    <p>2 bathrooms,</p>
                    <p>40m2 garden</p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <button>More Information</button>
        </div>
```

solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the component isn't re-rendering is because
The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the reference to the same array, now sorted.

Change your code to,

```
 setDb(
        [...db.sort(function (a, b) {
               return b.price - a.price
            })
        ]
    )
```

Comment: I want to add one more thing, although [..db.sort()] returns a new array but since your array contains objects, the items in the new array will reference to items of the old array. This in js is known as shallow copies. So read about it , because in react we should never mutate the state directly

Comment: thank you, I will apply your suggestions.

Comment: np, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
setDb(oldDb => [...oldDb].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price))
```

First copy the array, then sort